# How can I get all places marked with question marks on the map?

Tags: the-witcher-3

There are lots of interesting places to find, with nice loot sometimes. I've been hunting down question marks on the map, but I noticed that I don't have all of the places marked on my map yet for some reason.

I just destroyed a monster nest that was marked with a question mark, and found another one close by that wasn't marked on my map.

I know that reading the notice board can make places on the map, and I've read them all. But what can I do apart from that to mark all the interesting places on the map?

Answer (score 4):

So far my map got marked with question marks doing these actions:

- Reading notice board
- Overhearing conversation
- Talk to certain NPC
- Read notice/book you loot
- and obviously quests

Comment: Also be sure to visit Notice Boards more than once. Quite often you'll find new postings on boards you've already visited.

Comment: The notice boards will be marked with an exclamation mark and be yellow. These boards will be updated map-wide, so zoom out and check them out!

Comment: Actually quests won't add new question marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase maps at some of the shop locations in the Skellige Isles, that will add a bunch of locations. I have found some are VERY difficult to get to - some are underground and their entrances may be at a different location than the ? on your map.